# Can't Insert Row into Table (Column Count Mismatch)

Tags: mysql, insert

I've got a script that's creating a table, and then inserting a row afterwards.  Here is my SQL code executing to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE polls ( 
    id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    author VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    created DATETIME NOT NULL,
    expires DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
```

And here is where I add a new row:

```
INSERT INTO polls
VALUES ('TestPoll'),('Billy Bob'),('2013-05-01 04:17:31'),('2013-05-01 04:17:31')
```

**or**

```
INSERT INTO polls
VALUES ('TestPoll','Billy Bob','2013-05-01 04:17:31','2013-05-01 04:17:31')
```

*(I get the same error regardless)*

I always get this error:

```
<class '_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError'>, OperationalError(1136, "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"), <traceback object at 0x7f7bed982560>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, try:

```
INSERT INTO polls
VALUES ('TestPoll','Billy Bob','2013-05-01 04:17:31','2013-05-01 04:17:31')
```

but if your table structure changes, your code will break, a safer version is:

```
INSERT INTO polls (name, author, created, expires)
VALUES ('TestPoll','Billy Bob','2013-05-01 04:17:31','2013-05-01 04:17:31')
```

Comment: try the second version with the column names.

Answer (score 0):

Your `INSERT` query is not correctly formatted.

```
INSERT INTO polls (name, author, created, expires)
VALUES ('TestPoll','Billy Bob','2013-05-01 04:17:31','2013-05-01 04:17:31');
```

For more information, visit MySQL Reference Manual for the [INSERT statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html).

EDIT: It's always a good idea to explicitly type each column name, in case the table structure will change in some foreseeable future.

Answer (score 0):

In **mysql** you have to pass column name in your insert query.After assigning column  name your query will look like

```
INSERT INTO polls (name,author,created,expires) values ('TestPoll','Billy Bob','2013-05-01 04:17:31','2013-05-01 04:17:31');
```

Hope it helps.